# How to explain the different behaviour of spring in eclipse and standalone application

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jar, classpath

We have a web application using spring framework which works well. We try to use the same spring context in a standalone application built with maven. We managed to get the context by launching the application within eclipse, a main class instantiates the Spring context with the following lines:

```
ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");
```

But when we build a jar with maven and launch it with a command line we encounter errors. Here is the command line:

```
java -jar application.jar
```

The jar contains a META-INF that defines the classpath generated by maven-jar-plugin.

First spring failed on this error

```
Unable to locate NamespaceHandler when using context:annotation-config
```

We solved the problem by merging the different spring.handler files from maven spring jars and putting the result in our application.jar. This is a common solution to this problem but this doesn't explain why this failed in standalone mode but worked in a web app and in eclipse. Eclipse and standalone use the same code (java and spring configuration files).

Now we are facing a second problem, some beans instantiations fail. Some of our beans are declared with XML, some other beans are declared with annotations. Beans declared with annotations are not instantiated in standalone mode, traces in constructors show it, so instantiation of XML beans referencing these beans fails. We didn't solve this problem yet.

We don't understand why we observe a different behavior in eclipse or in standalone mode. What can explain the difference ? How does eclipse call java, how does-it set the classpath ?

Thanks for any response,
Mickaël

Comment: Eclipse generates a `bin` folder in your project and uses that as the classpath.